# Can I export SQL relationships to PowerBI?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, powerbi-datasource

If I have a SQL database with more than 100 tables and their relationships, will I be able to connect to SQl database and also have their relationships exported to POWERBI?

Comment: *and their relationships* Do you mean foreign keys?

Comment: What do you mean by "relationships exported to POWERBI"? By default Power BI will detect the relationships (either by using FK definitions and column names) and add them to the model. What exactly is the expected outcome?